# Facebook Graph Api Explorer: Getting different results than notifications area

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I'm using Graph Api Explorer to get the links of unseen comments on my ads because comments usually disappear from notification area within less than 2 hours.

Ex: When I use the Graph Api, It shows that I got 3 comments and when I visit the notification area, I see that I got 5 after the last time I used the Graph Api.

I kept in mind that:

1. Notifications area my give the link twice if there are 2
   comments.
2. If I use the graph and get results, those results won't appear
   again even if I don't click on the links.
3. It's a must that I don't view the pages of the comments to appear
   on the Graph Api even by clicking on the link directly.

We are using Page notifications API:
https://developers.facebook.com/.../v2.5/page/notifications

calling : https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/PAGEID/notifications/...
And the results returned sometimes are different than returned from the notifications area.

Permissons granted to the token are : manage_pages, public_profile

Results returned from Graph are just 3
Results found in Notifications Area are 5 ..

It's different from time to time but most of the time we don't get all the results on the graph.

Can you tell me why the results aren't the same as what we usually get on notifications (comments) are?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the user security configuration. There are many reasons but the first that comes to my mind is when a user disables Graph API. You should not expect to get exactly the same through the API than what you see in the desktop App although they should be quite similar often. I hope it helps.